# rendering object obtained using document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, dom

In javascript, i want to get an element and render it inside other element.

I am using following code

```
document.getElementById('table_cell1').innerHTML = document.getElementById("txt_area");
```

but this will not render the element, instead it will display

```
[object HTMLTextAreaElement]
```

one way to achieve this is, I wrap my 'text element' inside a DIV tag and then use innerHTML of DIV. e.g.

```
document.getElementById('table_cell1').innerHTML = document.getElementById("div_txt").innerHTML;
```

But this will require a lot of design change. So i am looking for some better way of doing the same.

Suggestions/Comments, Please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById('table_cell1').innerHTML = document.getElementById("txt_area").outerHTML;
```

Comment: thnx. this was too simple. i could have digged it more.

Comment: will this also include element's events? or just its's HTML? I actually want the cloned object that will have same attributes and events

Comment: It just copies the HTML with the attributes, event handlers attached by js won't be copied automatically.

Comment: can you also tell, how to copy event handlers attached by js?

Comment: You can either inline the event handler for ex: `<textarea onclick="...`, this gets copied since it is an attribute or you have to attach the event handlers (like you did for the original object) a second time for the copy.